# Reverter redirecionamento 301

Tags: php, aplicação-web, http

No arquivo index.php, por acidente escrevi o seguinte código:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.habbo.com.br");
?>
```

O redirecionamento era para ser apenas temporário. Agora, mesmo excluindo o arquivo e criando outro não consigo mais fazer para que a página seja carregada nesse mesmo arquivo index.php.

Como reverto isso?

Comment: Não há conteúdo no .htaccess.

Comment: Só fez a modificação nesse arquivo ou em outros ?

Comment: Somente nesse. Eu ainda tentei fazer um redirecionamento temporário, e botar um conteúdo qualquer no arquivo. Mas não volta.

Comment: Você usa o filezilla para subir os arquivos?

Answer (score 0):

Vai no arquivo .htaccess e mude de:

> RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

para

```
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=307]
```